# Named binding - MVC3

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm trying to register to implementations of same interface using named instances

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<CachedRepository>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<DbRepository>().InSingletonScope().Named("db");
```

the idea, is that if I not specify the name then the CachedRepository gets created, if I need a DB oriented one then I'd use the Named attribute, but this miserable fails when a simple object would get created

```
public class TripManagerController : Controller
    {
        [Inject]
        public IRepository Repository { get; set; } // default Cached repo must be created

        public TripManagerController()
        {
            ViewBag.LogedEmail = "test@test.com";
        }
}
```

the error is

> Error activating IRepository More than one matching bindings are
>   available. Activation path:   2) Injection of dependency IRepository
>   into parameter repository of constructor of type TripManagerController
>   1) Request for TripManagerController
>
> Suggestions:   1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for
>   IRepository only once.

Is there a way to achieve what I want without creating a new interface for BD oriented repositories?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

The `[Named]` attribute [as shown in the wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) should work.

BTW stay away from anything other than ctor injection!

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you cannot do what you're trying, I've just come across the same issue and as well as finding your question I also found this one where the author of Ninject [Remo Gloor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448580/remo-gloor) replied.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051391/495964

While [Remo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448580/remo-gloor) didn't explicitly say it couldn't be done his answer was to name both bindings (or use custom [attribute binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#specifying-constraints-on-the-type-binding-using-the-built-in-attribute-based-helpers), amounting the same thing).